# VB.NET Missing ID on new datarow in dataset

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagrid, dataset, dataadapter

I have got a problem with establishing ID of a new dataset entry. The new entry is returning NullValue for ID but if i get item(1) or bigger then i get normal data.

```
    Dim id as integer

    dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
    TheDatabase = "\dbMag.mdb"
    MyDocFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    FullDatabasePath = MyDocFolder & TheDatabase
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    Try
        con.Open()
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM mag"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "mag")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Błąd: ", Err.Description)
    End Try

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    dsNewRow = ds.Tables("mag").NewRow()
    With dsNewRow
        'do something
    end with
    ds.Tables("mag").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
    da.Update(ds, "mag")
    lastrow = ds.Tables("mag").Rows.Count - 1
    id = ds.Tables("mag").Rows(lastrow).Item(0)
```

id is returning NullValue

Comment: IDs that are auto-generated by the database don't just magically appear in your application. You have to pull them back. With a proper database like SQL Server, that's very simple. With Access, it's a bit more involved. You might benefit by reading [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052). Once you have resolved your issue with that information, be sure to post an answer to your question and accept it, if someone else hasn't already posted an answer. Questions should not be left unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
        Dim identity = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
        Dim cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(identity, con)
        id = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```